# Where to put Firebase clound function for collaboration

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

It may sound like a really trivial question, But i am developing an Android App with some friends and of course, we use GitHub to collaborate. However, for the server-side logic I am not sure where to store them for collaboration, Do I init a new repo only for those clound functions? Or store them together with my Android app source code?

Comment: Whatever you prefer.

Answer (score -1):

Generally there is a huge discussion how to do such things. I think that you have to decide by yourself depending of your team structure and technologies used. Personally,  once upon a time, I preferred to have them separately, however I then I started to work in huge project which was in one huge SVN repo and it was working good as well. Since than I am not so sure anymore...

In my opinion most important is to align with all team members regarding rules to make them all understand rules and follow the rules in the project.

I can provide you some links for interesting articles/discussions:

[link1](https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/5k1k2a/should_the_backend_and_frontend_of_a_site_be_in/), [link2](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/194822/when-to-separate-a-project-in-multiple-subprojects), [link3](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/213658/two-or-one-git-repo-for-android-app-web-service-backend), [link4](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2019/07/yarn-workspaces-organize-project-codebase-pro/)

I hope it will help!